# Endoresement Failure during query

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

while running the secured-asset transfer in hyperledger fabric I am getting this error and the query command is not passing

Command:-
**peer chaincode query -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile "${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem" -C mychannel -n secured -c '{"function":"GetAssetPrivateProperties","Args":["asset1"]}'**

Error:-
Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"asset private details does not exist in client org's collection: asset1"

Can anyone help me with it ??

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown from the chaincode. Make sure you have added the data to the private data collection with the key 'asset1' before querying it. Also, orderer endpoints are not required for query command.

peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n basic -c '{"function":"GetAssetPrivateProperties","Args":["asset1"]}'

Answer (score 0):

The source code from the  hyperledger /fabric-samples seems is not compatible with the command provided in the hyperledger fabric document.

Change the code in the repository of

**fabric-samples/asset-transfer-secured-agreement/chaincode-go/asset_transfer.go**

Add argument `asset_id string` to this function head.
`CreateAsset(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface,asset_id string, publicDescription string)`

In this function body
comment this line `assetID := hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))`

and reset the `assetID := asset_id`

hope helpful